# Несколько OR в одном sql запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю форму поиска по нескольким полям. Т.е. каждое поле должно искать результ из соответствующей колонки в базе. Как сформулировать этот запрос? Полей 6, не всегда они заполнены, для этого и использую OR.

Comment: ну это зависит в первую отчередь от того, что вы хотите найти, записи где совпадает хотя бы одно заданное условие или в которых совпадают сразу все условия. Вообще проще всего было бы вообще не добавлять в запрос условия по незаполненным полям

Comment: "SELECT * FROM objects WHERE ID='$id1' or tower='$tower1' or adress='$adress1' or floor='$floor1' or area='$area1' or undonds='$undonds1' or price='$price1'"
Мой запрос таков, но фильтрации не происходит.
Совпадать должно хотя бы одно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была когда-то, такая проблема, то есть были поля которые не факт что заполнены, я решил ее, фильтрацией данных до запроса, вот моя реализация, она на RedBean, но там все интуитивно. https://pastebin.com/xiWVTgNV

```
<?php

public function objects($dataPG)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `the_property` WHERE `addr` <> ' '";

    $ltr_binds = array();
    foreach( $dataPG as $k => $v )
    {
        if( !empty(trim($v)) && $v != ',' )
        {
            if( !in_array($k, array('start', 'last', 'go', 'all')) )
            {
                if( $k == 'price' )
                {
                    list($start, $last) = explode(',', $v);

                    if( !empty(trim($start)) )
                    {
                        $query .= ' AND `'.$k.'` >= ?';
                        $ltr_binds[] = $start;
                    }

                    if( !empty(trim($last)) )
                    {
                        $query .= ' AND `'.$k.'` <= ?';
                        $ltr_binds[] = $last;
                    }
                } else
                {
                    $query .= ' AND `'.$k.'` = ?';
                    $ltr_binds[] = $v;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // prepare & query
    $pq = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $pq->execute( $ltr_binds );
    return $pq->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```